# IOCTL String from user_mode adds weird caracters

Tags: c++, c, winapi, kernel, wdk

I'm trying to pass a string from my user mode application (C++) to my kernel driver (C).

User mode :

```
const char* welcome = "Hello from user mode\0";
bResult = DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IO_PRINT_MSG_REQUEST, (char*)welcome, strlen(welcome),
                NULL, 0, &Bytes, NULL);
```

Kernel mode :

```
case IO_PRINT_MSG_REQUEST:
        buffer = irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
        DbgPrint("IOCTL HELLO.");
        DbgPrint("Message received : %s\n", buffer);
```

My KM is printing :

Message received : Hello from user mode€Õ[

And sometimes it works. (added chars are always different).

Comment: Typo?  The code does not send the terminating `0`. Change `strlen(welcome)` to `strlen(welcome) + 1`.

Comment: one hint - implement [`FastIoDeviceControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_fast_io_dispatch) in self driver. if you not need return status_pending and call another driver - this more easy and more efficient way, compare Irp path

Comment: also you always must check in kernel that passed data is correct. in concrete case - that string is 0 terminated (or you can go out of system buffer and even from valid memory range). you have `InputBufferLength`. and can use also `%.*s` format